# Merging git branches. My local branch has hundreds of small edits in many files that have been moved on master

Tags: git

I've made small edits in hundreds of files in my local branch. Most of those files have been moved elsewhere in master, but have been marked as deleted by git when I pulled latest master. What I want to do locally:
1. move my edited files into the locations they are in in master 
2. merge master
3. deal with a hopefully small number of merge conflicts

Does this sound like the best way to fix this problem?

Comment: It's always hard to say *best* but this seems like the right way to me.

Comment: I presume you've branched of from master at some point? May be worth trying a rebase first? Even if you prefer the merge option. Assuming those files were originally in the same in master where you still have them on our branch. Maybe try the merge without moving them. If you do not like what you see, you can always go back and try another approach. ;)